# "TypeError: got multiple values for argument" after applying functools.partial()

Tags: python

Consider the following piece of code that utilizes [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```python
import functools

def add(a, b):
    return a + b

add_10 = functools.partial(add, a=10)
add_10(4)
```

When I run it, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    add_10(4)
TypeError: add() got multiple values for argument 'a'
```

When I change the keyword argument to a positional argument in the penultimate line, it passes:

```python
add_10 = functools.partial(add, 10)
```

Why doesn't it pass in the first case? I'm using Python 3.4.

Answer (score 25):

```
import functools

def add(a, b):
    return a + b

add_10 = functools.partial(add, b=10)

add_10(4)
```

This code will work. Function arguments with default value have to be at the end. So b=10 instead of a=10

Comment: Or just don't name the argument. add_10 = functools.partial(add, 10)

But in that case you're fixing a and not b.