# Dynamically fix function parameters in python?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, higher-order-functions

Consider some generic function of many parameters:

```
def my_fun(x, a, b, c, d, e, f, g):
    return x, a, b, c, d, e, f, g
```

I want to create a kind of higher order function, which fixes an arbitrary collection of parameters of my_fun. For example:

```
fixing_function({"a": 100, "e": 200})
```

should return a function that looks like this:

```
def fixed_function(x, b, c, d, f, g):
    return x, 100, b, c, d, 200, f, g
```

It would be easy to do using exec, but I am sure there must be a more pythonic way to do something like this. The motivation for this question is the use of scipy.optimize.curve_fit(). I need to fit my_fun several times, changing which parameters are fixed and which are fitted. To my knowledge, this precludes using *args and **kwargs in the definition of my_fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if the following is "more pythonic" or more efficient, but at least it does the job in this particular case:

```
from inspect import signature

def my_fun(x, a, b, c, d, e, f, g):
    return x, a, b, c, d, e, f, g

def fixing_function(orig_function, fixing_dict):
    orig_params = signature(orig_function).parameters
    remainingArgs = [key for key in orig_params.keys() if key not in fixing_dict]

    def new_function(*pos_args):
        zipped = dict(zip(remainingArgs, pos_args))
        new_args = zipped | fixing_dict
        return orig_function(**new_args)

    return new_function

fixed_function = fixing_function(my_fun, {"a": 100, "e": 200})

print(fixed_function(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
#output: (1, 100, 2, 3, 4, 200, 5, 6)
```

However, it does not fit OP's purpose, as can be seen from how `print(getfullargspec(fixed_function))` results in `FullArgSpec(args=[], varargs='pos_args', varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})` (nevertheless, it may be useful to other people).

---

In case someone else wonders, here is my attempt using eval to satisfy getfullargspec as well:

```
from inspect import signature, getfullargspec

def my_fun(x, a, b, c, d, e, f, g):
    return x, a, b, c, d, e, f, g

def fixing_function(orig_function, fixing_dict):
    orig_params = signature(orig_function).parameters
    remainingArgs = [key for key in orig_params.keys() if key not in fixing_dict]
    argSubtitute = [str(fixing_dict[key]) if key in fixing_dict else key for key in orig_params.keys()]
    partialF = f"lambda {','.join(remainingArgs)}:{orig_function.__name__}({','.join(argSubtitute)})"
    return eval(partialF)

fixed_function = fixing_function(my_fun, {"a": 100, "e": 200})  

print(fixed_function(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
#output: (1, 100, 2, 3, 4, 200, 5, 6)
print(getfullargspec(fixed_function))
#output: FullArgSpec(args=['x', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'g'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
```

There should be some ways it can be improved.

Comment: Can you use: `orig_params.keys()` so that you don't have to have the unused `_` variable?

Comment: @quamrana correct, I'll edit the answer

Comment: Lovely answer. Unfortunately, for my purpose it won't work as scipy.optimize.curve_fit() can't determine the number of fitting parameters by using getfullargspec on the new_function.

Comment: @Heisenbugs I thought I might draw an inspiration from `partial`, and I found a .py version ( https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/functools.py ) and a .c version ( https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_functoolsmodule.c ).
But using the .py version, `inspect.getfullargspec` will get the signature of the `__call__`, namely `FullArgSpec(args=['self'], varargs='args', varkw='keywords', defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})`. I thought of doing something with C, but then it would be about "`low-level detail of the CPython implementation`".

Comment: I'll add my attempt at satisfying getfullargspec using eval, while hoping that someone else may get a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are passing named parameters, you could use a closure

```py
def outer(**some_params):
    def inner(**more_params):
        return {**some_params, **more_params}
    return inner
```

> if you are using a much older version of python you might need a function to merge the two dicts

Comment: I tried using partial, like `fixed_function2 = partial(my_fun, **{"a": 100, "e": 200} )` and `print(fixed_function2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))` and it results in `TypeError: my_fun() got multiple values for argument 'a'`. Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: @qrsngky See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26182068/typeerror-got-multiple-values-for-argument-after-applying-functools-partial. Its unfortunate that it can't work it out by itself...

Comment: @Heisenbugs it may be a bit troublesome to handle cases of "insertion in the middle". And not many people request anything similar, so they never implemented it.

Comment: @blue_note the OP relies on the usage of `getfullargspec`. The current version of the answer would result in `FullArgSpec(args=[], varargs=None, varkw='more_params', defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})` and therefore won't fit OP's use case.